# JPA No Persistence provider for EntityManager after maven build

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have a JPA project that is working just fine, I run maven build to create a jar with dependencies, the created jar throws an exception: `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PersistenceUnit`, I know that this is because of not having a provider inside persistence, but the provider is specified and working fine before building! Why is that? 
I ran maven build with clean install goal
persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:src\main.db" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.asendar.applications.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />

    </properties>


</persistence-unit>
```

pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.asendar.applications.main.TerminalMain</mainClass>
    <jee.version>7.0</jee.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>asendar-codes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.asendar.applications.main.TerminalMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.asendar.applications.main.TerminalMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guigarage</groupId>
        <artifactId>flatter</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- sqlite -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA and hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: where did you put the persistence.xml in maven dir structure? And why do you need two `hibernate.dialect`s? And where are the classes to be managed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that starting of `hibernate-4`, you should use `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`